# Android TextInputLayout transitionName and transitionGroup - what is the purpose?

Tags: android, firebase

I am taking a look at the [firebaseUI auth project](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)

and I see a few `TextInputLayouts` that make reference to transitionName and transitionGroup but I can't find anything yet online to help me understand how to use them and what is the true purpose:

here is an example, please look at the android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout's :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/FirebaseUI.WrapperStyle">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            fontPath="fonts/Medium-Extd.otf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:text="@string/fui_welcome"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
            tools:text="welcome" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_layout"
            style="@style/FirebaseUI.TextInputLayout.EmailField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:transitionGroup="true"
            android:transitionName="@string/fui_email_field_name"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:textColor="@color/fui_white"
                tools:text="johndoe@msn.com"
                style="@style/FirebaseUI.TextInputEditText.EmailField" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/name_layout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/email_layout"
            style="@style/FirebaseUI.TextInputLayout.NameField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                style="@style/FirebaseUI.TextInputEditText.NameField"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                tools:text="john doe"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/password_layout"
            style="@style/FirebaseUI.TextInputLayout.PasswordField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/name_layout"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fui_field_padding_vert"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@color/fui_white"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                tools:text="123456789"
                style="@style/FirebaseUI.TextInputEditText.PasswordField" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/create_account_text"
            style="@style/FirebaseUI.Text.BodyText"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/password_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fui_field_padding_vert"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            tools:text="@string/fui_create_account_preamble_tos_and_pp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_create"
            style="@style/FirebaseUI.Button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:text="@string/fui_signup"
            tools:text="sign up"
            fontPath="fonts/Medium-Extd.otf"
            android:textColor="@color/fui_black"
android:layout_below="@id/create_account_text"
            tools:ignore="MissingPrefix,RtlHardcoded" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/fui_mylogo"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I've tried not using them but I can't tell what it does still.

Comment: Check this article https://android.jlelse.eu/easy-android-shared-element-transition-ac36952a4a4

Comment: i found this easier to understand http://mikescamell.com/shared-element-transitions-part-1/ . i really appreciate the article you offered also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them deal with shared element transition. A Transition holds information about animations that will be run on its targets during a scene change. Based on the documentation:

**transitionName**

> The name used of the View to be used to identify Views in Transitions
>   or null if no name has been given.

Its basically name of your View which will be used for identification purpose during Transitions.

**isTransitionGroup**

> Whether or not the ViewGroup should be treated as a unit in Activity
>   transitions. If false, the ViewGroup won't transition, only its
>   children. If true, the entire ViewGroup will transition together.

It determines if Transition characteristic should be imposed on the ViewGroup as a whole of just the childern of the group.

Answer (score 1):

`transitionGroup` and `transitionName` are used for shared element transitions between different layouts. [Reference](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html)